# How to inject HTTP in jasmine with a real connection

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How to realize a jasmine test using http injection with a real backend?

I means that I would like to test my service using a real http connection

```
import { provide }                                               from '@angular/core';
import{ClassCall} from 'xx.xx'

import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, XHRBackend, Http} from "@angular/http";
import {MockBackend} from "@angular/http/testing/mock_backend";
import {beforeEachProviders} from "@angular/core/testing/testing";
import {inject} from "@angular/core/testing/test_injector";
import {async} from "@angular/core/testing/async";



describe('HttpService Tests', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => {
    return [
      HTTP_PROVIDERS,
      Http,
      ClassCall,
      provide(ClassCall, {useClass: Http}),
    ];
  })

    it('should return response when subscribed to postRequest',
      async(inject([ClassCall], (myCall: ClassCall) => {

        myCall.Call("hey", "there")
          .then((response)=>{
            expect(response).toBe("anyResponse")
          })
      })));
  });
```

I have not seen any topics about it....

Many thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As igorzg says the correct way in rc4 is to do

```
beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([MyService, Http, ConnectionBackend, HTTP_PROVIDERS, XHRBackend]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since RC.5 you must use [TestBed.configureTestingModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/TestBed-class.html#!#configureTestingModule-anchor) to configure your modules.

So in your test case in beforeEachProviders you must use it eg:

```
class HttpMock {
    post(url, content, requestOptions) {
      return {
        toPromise() {
          return Promise.resolve(url);
        }
      }
    }

  }


describe('HttpService Tests', () => {
  let countryMock = new CountryMock();
  let navigationMock = new NavigationServiceMock();
  let httpMock = new HttpMock();
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {provide: Http, useValue: httpMock},
        {provide: CountryService, useValue: countryMock},
        {provide: NavigationService, useValue: navigationMock},
        AuthService
      ]
    });
  });
  it('should check canActivate and set country de/login', inject([AuthService], (auth: AuthService) => {
    expect(auth).toBeTruthy();
    spyOn(countryMock, "getCountry").and.returnValue({code: 'de'});
    spyOn(auth, "isLoggedIn").and.returnValue(false);
    spyOn(navigationMock, "navigateByUrl").and.callThrough();
    expect(auth.canActivate()).toBeFalsy();
    expect(auth.isLoggedIn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(navigationMock.navigateByUrl).toHaveBeenCalledWith('de/login');
  }));
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, however, i forget to precise that i'm using Ionic 2 and so i'm locked to angular 2.0.0.0rc4 ...
I tried to change my code based on your advices.
but it still wont works ....
i get an error : 'no providers for AuthService ...
injection seems to not work

Comment: You have to put your onwn class AuthService is just my example from my services ;)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: in rc.4 you need to use addProviders

Live example https://plnkr.co/edit/XhIkgR92oHRH4rIotXCj?p=preview

```
import {addProviders, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {MyService} from './myservice';

describe('my code', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([MyService]);
  });

  it('does stuff', inject([MyService], (service) => {
    // actual test
  }));
});
```

Comment: Aggr there is something wrong with plnkr sec i will create another one

Comment: great tanks !!! may you also know how to wait for an async contructor injected ??